# Curious about these operators

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
    _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
    [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}];
```

I was curious if anyone could explain to me what the ? and the : do. I don't understand what is happening between the ? and the block. What does the ? 0.25 : 0.0 do exactly?

Comment: That link was perfect thanks.  When I was searching it kept giving me no results. Should have added operators.  Then it all came up.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: Exactly the same as in C, which you should know before you tackle Objective-C.

Answer (score -1):

it is the same as if-else statement. If not 0.25 then 0.0